# Can I run multiple sites off of one MAMP instance?

Tags: localhost

I have a php written API that isn't ready for deployment and an app that runs on that API. I'd like to simulate the client server situation via separately serving up both, but I want to do it locally

Is it possible to run multiple localhost domains? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume MAMP is another stack including apache httpd?

Then yes: research [Virtual Hosting with Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)